# Hide all elements with particular number in id

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help, I try to cut complexity and make simple example:

```
<div id="tree_div">
   <ul>
      <li id="tree_li_401">401</li>
      <li id="tree_li_101">101</li>
      <li id="tree_li_301">301</li>
      <li id="tree_li_201">201</li>
      <li id="tree_li_102">102</li>
      <li id="tree_li_402">402</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to hide all li elements base on **first number after tree_li_**

For example: I need to hide all elements which have number **4** after **tree_li_**:

```
<li id="tree_li_402">
<li id="tree_li_401">
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors to target those elements:

```
$('li[id^="tree_li_4"]').hide();
```

Here's a list of all the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) that jQuery supports.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, you can use attribute selectors, if you would like a solution for all of them, use the `.each()` method, and you could use a variable for the number.

example:

```
$("li[id='tree_li_'"+ magicNumber +"]").each(function (idx, li) {
  $(li).hide();
});
```

or as a one liner

```
$("li[id='tree_li_'"+ magicNumber +"]").hide();
```

and if you wanted to get really crazy, you could use the `.substring()` method.
`.substring` returns true, if the string has the specified substring.
i.e. `"brian".substring("ria")` will return with the index of the string (a positive number)
and if it does not find the string, it returns as -1.

```
$("li").each(function(idx, li) {
  if ($(li).attr("id").substring("4")) {
    $(li).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `filter`: `$('li').filter(function() { return this.id.match(/^tree_li_\d+/); }).hide()`.